# About integration taking the sphere volume as an example (find the error)

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have heard a lot about rotation and how you can use it to calculate the volumes of different bodies. 
There is something though which has troubled me for a long time. 
If you take the area of half a disk : $\mathscr{A}/2 =   \frac{\pi r^{2}}{2}$ 
and that you argue that by integrating it from $0$ to $2\pi$ you will have accomplished a full rotation and should (as done with the volume of cones) now get the whole sphere, you arrive to the following result:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathscr{A}/2 \; d\theta = \pi^{2}r^{2} $$ 
Which is obviously false. 
Now here is my question, where did I do something wrong ?